# If-else statement using list, Generalized statement

Tags: python, list, if-statement, int

I have five lists:

```
Values2 = ['0','1']
Values3 = ['0','1','2']
Values4 = ['0','1','2','3']
Values5 = ['0','1','2','3','4']
Values6 = ['0','1','2','3','4','5']
```

These values inside each list varies from 0 to 5, for Example `values2` becomes `['2','5']`

Now my if-else statement for first List `values2` is as below:

```
if(int(Values[0]) <= int(Values[1])):
    myAction1(Values[1]) 
else: 
    NoOfMoves = int(Values[0])-int(Values[1])
    myAction2(NoOfMoves)
```

Can anyone guide me with how to generalize this Statement, so that it work for every list.

Comment: How does it go from `['0','1']` to `['2','5']`

Comment: Question is not clear. Could you please explain more?

Comment: Have previous code, if i include them, it may create confusion,

Comment: You should show an example of what you want to get at least for the case of a list with three elements.

Comment: @Mr.Calm If we understand the specialized conditions, we can try to generalize. So, please explain the code which you have given in the question.

Comment: @thefourtheeye,Actually these lists are from Permutations `values2` list is `['0','1']``['0','2']``['0','3']...['1','3'].....['5','4']` and my statement is for only this list, my question is to make my Statement generalize for every list, list with size 2,3,4,5,6.

Answer (score 0):

You could create list of lists and iterate over it.
example:

```
>>> a = range(1)
>>> c = range(10)
>>> b = range(4)
>>> b = range(7)
>>> a
[0, 1, 2, 3]
>>> b
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
>>> c
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>>
>>> [a,b,c]
[[0, 1, 2, 3], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]]
>>>
>>> for lst in [a,b,c]:
...     print lst
...
[0, 1, 2, 3]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> for lst in [a,b,c]:
...     for element in lst:
...             print element
...
0
1
...
```